# GPT Protective Partition

Tags: windows-8.1, usb-storage, gpt, usb-3, portable-harddrive

I’ve moved my 3TB hard drive to another USB enclosure, and it no longer works.
Disk manager says “2794.52 GB Healthy (GPT Protective Partition)”.

How to fix that?

I don’t want to reformat, I need the data from that hard drive.

Currently I’m using Windows 8.1 x64, AFAIR the drive was partitioned by Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Sounds like the controller on the enclosure does not support 3tb drives

Comment: @Ramhound the manufacturer says “Hard Drives up to 3TB”: http://www.thermaltakeusa.com/store/ProductPrint.aspx?C=1023&ID=1866

Comment: What exactly is Afair?

Comment: @Ramhound As Far As I Remember. I'm not sure which one I've bought first, the Win8 upgrade or that 3TB hard drive.

Comment: I have the exact same problem and the other USB enclosure I'm using works with big hard drives since I had my 4TB formated in GPT there before. Only difference for me is that I'm using a 6TB hard drive and I made the GPT with Windows 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to solve this, so I've just moved the HDD back to the older USB enclosure, where it works great.

I think it could be a hardware or driver issue. Looks like different USB 3.0 to SATA chipsets have slightly different characteristics, which result in incompatible file systems when the HDD is moved between the USB enclosures :-(

**Update:** since that time, I've bought a new desktop and connected that HDD directly to SATA without USB. The file system was recognized OK.

Comment: This is not a solution and it should not be marked as accepted answer, because you provided a workaround (most obvious, at that).

Answer (score 0):

Your GPT partition table seems to have been corrupted/wiped out/otherwise made unrecognizable by windows. Use gdisk on the disk and see what it reports. If it shows either the absence of GPT, or some corruption, use the repair options available.

More info : http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html

Comment: How's the GPT partition becomes uncorrupted once I return the HDD to the old USB enclosure?

Comment: @Soonts Eh?? This is weird... Can you download a partition manager, say Easeus or paragon or etc, and check whether it says the same thing?

Comment: I've changed enclosure to the old one, and left it there. Apparently, it was a bad idea to fix things that weren't broken.. But thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: @Soonts problems crop up anyway, no need to give up so fast. Why don't you download active@ partition manager from http://www.pcdisk.com/ and take a screenshot and post it?